# How to use Power Automate to automatically add comment to Planner task when assigned to the task?

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-planner

Microsoft Planner doesn't notify the people attached to a task when comments are made on the task. I read from the Microsoft website that Planner will send a notice that someone has commented on a task if you have previously commented on the task. Instead of commenting "adding comment to receive update notifications" to every task that I am assigned to, I want to use Power Automate to do it.

I tried many different flows, but I thought that the attached image seemed to be the closest to what I was trying to achieve. Comments weren't being added to the tasks that I was assigned to though.

Flow to add comment to task when assigned

[image: 1]

If it would be easier to make a flow to send an email every time a comment is made on a task that I am assigned to, I'd be open to that solution also.

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot, you are getting events from Planner, but then making the request to create a comment in, what looks like, SharePoint lists. Those are unrelated services. Assuming your tasks are in Planner: the comments on Planner tasks are Group conversations. You can create one using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365groupsmail/). Then you'll need to put the id of the conversation in the task's ConversationThreadId field to link the conversation to the task.